# Mapping MySQL Tables through EF is (erroneously) showing Navigation Properties

Tags: mysql, winforms, entity-framework, edmx

I'm mapping MySQL table to a CLR Object and there is no errors in mapping/generating entity code.

When I try to get all records of that object (Dept), the navigation property (Employees) is shown in the DataGridView as a 4th column. Here is the Dept class properties:

```
DEPT
{
  ID,
  NAME,
  CREATEDATE,
  EMPs (Navigational property based on a relationship with Employees table)
}
```

What do I expect? I expect normally for 3 columns to be shown in the DataGridView instead of 4 columns. What I mean, I expect that Navigation Properties should not be shown in the DataGridView.

**P.S:** I enable lazy loading of the context.

Comment: I think it's a behaviour of the `DataGridView` which doesn't know anything about entity framework and navigation properties. It just takes (by default) all properties of the object and creates a column for it (for complex properties probably calling `ToString()`). You should extend your tags by the UI tech (ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, ...???) you are using the `DataGridView` with, because I think the solution is proper customization of the grid view, not of EF mapping.

Comment: But when I map Oracle table, the same `DataGridView` does not show the 4th column.